# Does the children of binary trees have to be ordered lexiconically or numerically?

Tags: binary-tree

Are both of these binary trees?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, both are binary trees. A binary tree is a tree with maximum two childs, a left and a right one.

Maybe you have in mind the Binary Search Tree, where all the children on the left are smaller than the root and all the ones at the right are bigger